# Load iOS tab content only once

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm writing an iOS app that provides a native tabbed interface to a bunch of WebViews that display content from my website. I want re-tapping the same tab to refresh the page, so I implemented (word choice? I'm a Java guy...) `UITabBarDelegate` in my ViewController and have this:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    AbstractPageController *otherController = (AbstractPageController *)[[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:[[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item]];
    [otherController loadPage];
}
```

Which loads a page in the appropriate WebView.

And, of course, to load the page in the first place (on startup), I have this in my `AbstractPageController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadPage];
}
```

As you might imagine, this results in the page being loaded twice if a new tab is selected. How do I avoid this? Right now I think the best idea is to remove the `loadPage` call from `viewDidLoad`, but that would mean that on startup the page didn't get loaded (right?). And it seems hacky to special-case that. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that the cleanest way was to simply have `tabBardidSelectItem` only do any work if the same tab was re-tapped. Thus:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    NSUInteger newIndex = [[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item];

    if (newIndex == [self selectedIndex])
        //etc
}
```

Works great, and doesn't feel hacky!

Answer (score -1):

I believe if you invoke the method -loadView rather than your own instance method, the view will remain loaded upon presentation and the duplication of loading will not occur.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: From the linked documentation of `loadView`:"You should never call this method directly"